# How can I compare a number to a previous highlighted number?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[image]

I'm stuck with few problems in google sheets. I have a solution to get the last number in a column

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(lookup(2,1/(A1:A20<>""),A1:A20))
```

but I'm not able to figure out how to solve the below scenarios. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

1. If 7b is more than 3 points compared to the last highlighted (green) number in 7B, then show "true"
2. If 7b or 5a is close to the last highlighted (green) number in B (ex: between a range of 1-3), then show "alert"
3. If the last number entered was in 8a then enter c7 as "done"

Comment: Are we trying to detect cell colors or are they green and blue for a reason?

Comment: @player0 Here is a sample of my sheet. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rezMGS2hjEy-lhRINf93frP_cJBjIYHiv13HJXx_xjQ/edit?usp=sharing
Right now I just manually highlight the cells but if that can be done with a formula, that would be awesome aswell.

Comment: @GabrielPierce yes, I'm trying to detect the cell colors. They can be any colors but it has to be 2 different colors in column A and B

Comment: what are your rules for painting the cells?

Comment: @player0 If the number moves from A to B then I need to paint the last number in cell A and if I move from B to A, I need the last number in cell B painted.

Comment: in that case this is possible to solve only with script where detection of background color is needed to determine the output

Comment: @player0 I can always do the highlights manually but the indications in Col C, D, E is what I'm mainly looking for